# The command "mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V" failed and exited with 1 during

Tags: travis-ci

I have setup my .travis.yml
as:

```
language: java
script: mvn clean verify
```

but I get

```
The command "mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V" failed and exited with 1 during
```

see
  https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/w3cValidator/blob/master/.travis.yml

**What is wrong with this setup? Why is mvn install executed when I ask for mvn verify?**

I had expected this to work based on:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33283409/1497139

and checking the .travis.yml with http://lint.travis-ci.org/

Comment: I am with the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I'd recommend using `install: true` and placing the commands for the build under the `script` element.

```
language: java
install: true
script:
- mvn install
```

There is an important difference between `install` and `script`: if the former fails, the build *errors*, if the latter one fails, the build *fails*. See the [docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Breaking-the-Build):

> If `before_install`, `install` or `before_script` return a non-zero exit code, the build is *errored* and stops immediately.
>
> If `script` returns a non-zero exit code, the build is *failed*, but continues to run before being marked as *failed*.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this style of yml file:

```
# this is a java project using maven
language: java
# install
install: mvn install
```