# GitHub - Travis ci job rejected

Tags: java, github, configuration, travis-ci

I am trying to integrate travis into my GitHub project.

Here is the `travis.yml` file:

```
language: java
```

I see all commits and pull requests in the UI, however it says job rejected in the status and not seems to run? Is that a configuration issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is necessary to provide the script to run.

See this *[hello world](https://github.com/travis-examples/travis-java-ant-example/blob/master/.travis.yml)* example.

Also, look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267878/example-of-travis-ci-yml-file-for-java) for a maven example.

References:

- Travis [Java Documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java)
- Travis [for Complete Beginners](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/for-beginners)

Comment: Thanks, I tried the script tag but didn't realize I need a new line after that

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the issue was that I named the file `travis.yml` instead of `.travis.yml` (Notice the leading dot).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had named the file as .travis.yaml(notice extra a) instead of .travis.yml